# Trouble using tfp.optimizer.lbfgs_minimize in a PINN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, deep-learning

I am designing a PINN for an exercise which is currently using adam optimiser.
I would like to use this optimizer:

```
tfp.optimizer.lbfgs_minimize(
  value_and_gradients_function,
  initial_position,
  num_correction_pairs=50,
  f_relative_tolerance=1.0 * np.finfo(float).eps,
  max_iterations=50000,
  max_line_search_iterations=50,
)
```

I have been looking at the datasheet and I have trouble understanding exactly what I need to put in "value_and_gradients_function" and "initial_position".

What I have is:

2 lists, one for the weights, one for the biases, containing tf variables (one for each layer). They look like this:

```
self.weights = [<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(2, 100) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'Variable_2:0' shape=(100, 100) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'Variable_4:0' shape=(100, 100) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'Variable_6:0' shape=(100, 100) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'Variable_8:0' shape=(100, 2) dtype=float32>]

self. biases = [<tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=(1, 100) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'Variable_3:0' shape=(1, 100) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'Variable_5:0' shape=(1, 100) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'Variable_7:0' shape=(1, 100) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'Variable_9:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32>]
```

A function which compute the network and return the output:

```
  self.neural_net(self, input, weights, biases)
```

Tensorflow graphs to compute a few things such as differentiation of the outputs with respect to the inputs. They look like this:

```
    self.Cg0_pred, self.Cs0_pred, _ = self.net_CgCs(self.x0_tf,self.t0_tf) 
    self.Cg_lb_pred, self.Cs_lb_pred, self.Cg_x_lb_pred = self.net_CgCs(self.x_lb_tf, self.t_lb_tf)
    _ , _ , self.Cg_x_ub_pred = self.net_CgCs(self.x_ub_tf, self.t_ub_tf)
    self.f_gp_pred, self.f_pp_pred = self.net_f_CgCs(self.x_f_tf, self.t_f_tf)
```

(self.x0_tf,self.t0_tf,self.x_lb_tf, self.t_lb_tf,self.x_ub_tf, self.t_ub_tf and self.x_f_tf, self.t_f_tf are basically lists containing the inputs to train the model)

a tensor using the tensorflow graphs to calculate the loss which looks like this:

```
  self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.u0_tf - self.u0_pred)) + \
    tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.v0_tf - self.v0_pred)) + \
    tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.u_lb_pred - self.u_ub_pred)) + \
    tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.v_lb_pred - self.v_ub_pred)) + \
    tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.u_x_lb_pred - self.u_x_ub_pred)) + \
    tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.v_x_lb_pred - self.v_x_ub_pred)) + \
    tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.f_u_pred)) + \
    tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.f_v_pred))
```

And, basically all I have for adam is to define the optimizer as such

```
self.train_op_Adam = self.optimizer_Adam.minimize(self.loss)
```

and then I just have to repeat this for each training:

```
self.sess.run(self.train_op_Adam, tf_dict)
```

What do I need to do to run this using LBFGS optimizer ?

I defined a function which basically just return the loss because tfp.optimizer.lbfgs_minimize require a callable.

```
  def loss_LBFGS(self,x):
    '''Callable returning the loss for the LBFGS optimizer'''
    return tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(self.Cg0_pred - self.Cg0_tf)) + \
                tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(self.Cs0_pred - self.Cs0_tf)) + \
                tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(self.ug * self.C0 
                                         - self.ug * self.Cg_lb_pred 
                                         + self.Dg * self.Cg_x_lb_pred)) + \
                tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(self.Cg_x_ub_pred)) + \
                tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(self.f_gp_pred)) + \
                tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(self.f_pp_pred))
```

That seems to be okay but unsure because I can not make it work anyway because I can't figure out what to do for the "initial_position" part. I have tried concactenating the weights and the biases or extending one with the other but I have an error telling me that the 2 lists should have the same shape.

```
ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 100 and 2. Shapes are [100,100] and [100,2].
    From merging shape 3 with other shapes. for '{{node minimize/initial_position/0}} = Pack[N=5, T=DT_FLOAT, axis=0](minimize/initial_position/0/ReadVariableOp, minimize/initial_position/0/ReadVariableOp_1, minimize/initial_position/0/ReadVariableOp_2, minimize/initial_position/0/ReadVariableOp_3, minimize/initial_position/0/ReadVariableOp_4)' with input shapes: [2,100], [100,100], [100,100], [100,100], [100,2].
```

I understand what it means, since the weights and biaises are indeed of different shapes, but I do not know how to tackle this issue.

Would anyone have an idea how to do that ? Also do you think what I did with the loss function is the right thing to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Tensorflow probability LBFGS optimizer for neural network training is complex since you need to do the interface. But You can use the interface done by [Deepxde](https://github.com/lululxvi/deepxde/tree/master/deepxde/optimizers/tensorflow). This is the repo where the interface is done. Other implementations are linked in the header of tfp_optimizer.py. They define a helper class that will dynamically associate the weights of the neural network to a vector containing the flatten and concatenated parameters and give it to the optimizer. After the LBFGS optimization the optimized weights are then applied back to the neural network.